# Mapping leveled items from a JSON list into a data frame in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have a data frame on trending YouTube videos that has an integer column `category_id` representing the ID of the video category. This ID is stored in a seperate .json file like that looks like:

```
{
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
   "id": "1",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation",
    "assignable": true
    }
  },
  {
    etc..
  }
 ]
}
```

As you can see the `"id"` is defined in the first level of the file and I would also need `"title"` through `snippet { }`.
I have imported the JSON data into R with the `rjson` library as follows:

```
library(rjson)
json_list <- fromJSON(file = "C:\\...\\US_category_id.json")
```

Which returns a list object of 1. When I try to turn this into a data frame through `json_df <- as.data.frame(json_list$items)` it returns a flat data frame of one row and a bunch of columns.

What is the best practice here to return a data frame on the .json file containing the `"id"` and `"title"` so I can combine it with my other data frame down the line?

Here's what the list object of 1 looks like in RStudio
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
pluck_json <- function(json, sel) {
  vapply(json, `[[`, character(1L), sel)
}

result <- data.frame(
  id = pluck_json(json_list$items, "id"), 
  title = pluck_json(json_list$items, c("snippet", "title"))
)
```

Comment: Creating the function went fine, but executing it as you passed results into the following error:  

`Error in vapply(json, `[[`, character(length(json)), sel) : 
  values must be length 32,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1`

 json_list$items is a list of 32. The arguments passed in the function seem fine

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be `character(1L)`. Plz try the new function. @Brayn